# Running ICC on a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I'm trying to calculate between sessions (session 1 and 2) ICC on two different tests (test 1 and test 2) in a data frame created in R.

Here is the data frame and the package I'd like to use:

```
df<-data.frame(subject=rep(1:10,4),session=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),test=c(rep("test1",20),rep("test2",20)), parameter=rnorm(40, mean=1.05, sd=0.50))
library(irr)
```

I have tried subsetting the data frame to isolate one test at the time but I'm struggling to apply icc by row (comparing test 1 to test 2). I guess there is a quicker way to calculate icc all at once. What I'm looking for is an output that could look like this:

```
 Test    ICC
 test1   (icc value)
 test2   (icc value)
```

Any idea how to do this?